# How to get the id of the outputfield texbox clicked by the user which is created inside <apex:repeat>?

Tags: apex, repeat, outputfield, data-repeater

I want the box id value when the user clicks on the output field. Here box is a custom object with two fields a checkbox and a textbox . when the user clicks at the output field in the repeat element , i want the id of the box object into the controller method save.

Object box contain two fields inputtextbox,checkbox

vf page

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="overflow:auto;width:750px;height:70%" >
  <apex:panelGrid columns="5" id="theGrid">
  <apex:repeat value="{!allBoxes}" var="box" id="theRepeat">
        <apex:outputField value="{!box.Boxfield__c}" onClick="{!save}"/><br/>
         </apex:repeat>
      </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

Controller

```
class mycontroller
{
    public List<Single_Box__c> allBoxes{get;set;}

public void save()
{
// i want the box id of the selected output field in this function so that i can do some processing in here

}
```

}

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide a concrete example, preferably with code, so that others can help you?

Comment: sorry i was little new to this website... hadnt known about the code formating first, that's why the question was little misleading @battery.cord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Wrapper class:

```
public class mycontroller{
    public List<BoxWrapper> allBoxes{get;set;}

    //some code to fetch the single boxes

    Single_Box__c someBox = new Single_Box__c(); //or other ways of fetching Single Boxes
    BoxWrapper b = new BoxWrapper();
    b.box = someBox;

    allBoxes.add(b);

    public class BoxWrapper{
        public Single_Box__c box { get; set; }

        public void save(){
            //do something with this.box
            this.box.Field__c = 'New Value';
            update this.box;
        }
    }
}
```

And then change your visualforce page to

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="overflow:auto;width:750px;height:70%" >
  <apex:panelGrid columns="5" id="theGrid">
      <apex:repeat value="{!allBoxes}" var="b" id="theRepeat">
          <apex:outputField value="{!b.box.Boxfield__c}" onClick="{!b.save}"/><br/>
      </apex:repeat>
  </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Hi @Fernando i want the id of the box object when the user clicks on <apex:outputField value="{!box.Boxfield__c}" onClick="{!save}"/><br/> . It will help me to update another field on box object.. do help me in this